# Why MongoDB Compass shows as connected even if the mongod process is not running?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Mongod is shut down as you can see in the following images, but still when I connect mongodb compass it gets connnected. I am not able to understand where it is getting connected.

I have made a C:/data/db folder, initialised mongo in it, changed path of mongo to it (--dbpath), also in env variable bin folder location is added. I am stuck with this problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdQ3P.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gcKz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHeiP.png)

Comment: do not post images, use plain text instead

Comment: Obviously it is running. I guess you try to start it a second time - which is not possible, thus it fails. However, a `mongod` instance is running.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551